# Как убрать надпись "Файл не выбран" и оставить только кнопку Обзор, используя CSS или HTML

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё что нужно это убрать надпись "Файл не выбран", помогите кто может.

```
            <div class="InputRegistration"><p>
                <label for="">
                    <p>Укажите вашу аватарку:</p>
                    <input type="file" name="file" class="SelectImage">
                </label>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для `div` в котором написан данный текст поставить свойство `display: none;`

сделать можно разными способами - поскольку кода вы не привели, то о структуре можно гадать и варинтов предложить много:

**если у текста за кнопкой есть индивидуальный класс**

```
.text_posle_knopki_obsor {
    display: none;
}
```

**если у текста за кнопкой есть id**

```
#text_posle_knopki_obsor {
    display: none;
}
```

**если у текста за кнопкой ничего нет**

```
button[value='Обзор'] + div {
    display: none;
}
```

ну или модификации данных подходов (особенно последнего)

P.S.

после того как код увидел - понятно, что предложенные методы не подходят

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

вот решение вашей проблемы

Comment: Спасибо большое, я кстати добавил свой код в описание, есть совет как лучше с помощью него убрать надпись

Comment: @HELL_4IRE, вот теперь более понятно - сейчас подумаю

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, жду

Comment: Добавлю что класс InputRegistration используется не только в тэге связанном с добавлением файла

Comment: для этого тэга есть класс SelectImage, его и хотел использовать для того, чтобы избавиться от чертовой надписи, ну не смотрится она там, хотя есть вариант лучше, это переместить эту надпись под кнопку Обзор и выровнять по центру

Comment: @HELL_4IRE, вот решение вашей проблемы - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035400/how-can-i-remove-the-no-file-chosen-tooltip-from-a-file-input-in-chrome

Comment: О, спасибо еще раз большое